# Does "U-SAT in P" imply "P=NP"

Tags: sat

Valiant & Vazirani proved SAT transforms UNIQUE SAT under randomized probabilistic reductions in polynomial time. Calabro et al. showed that UNIQUE k-SAT is as hard as k-SAT. Now the question is, if someone shows s that UNIQUE k-SAT is in P, does it imply P=NP?

References

L. G. Valiant and V. V. Vazirani, "NP is as easy as detecting unique solutions." Theoretical Computer Science 47:85–93, 1986. (PDF on ScienceDirect.)

C. Calabro, R. Impagliazzo, V. Kabanets and R. Paturi, "The Complexity of Unique k-SAT: An Isolation Lemma for k-CNFs". Journal of Computer and System Sciences 74(3):386–393, 2008. (PDF at ACM Digital Library; free PDF.)

Comment: There is standard reduction SAT to k-SAT and even to 3-SAT.

Comment: The reductions in the Calabro et el. paper are again randomized. So no, it doesn’t imply P = NP. See also http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~fortnow/papers/sep.ps .

Comment: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ is likely a more appropriate forum.

Comment: Therefore it should lead to "NP=RP", shouldn't it? Yes, but computer scientists are too busy to reply.

Comment: Yes, NP = RP sounds right. The Valiant-Vazirani reduction isn't a proper reduction as it has only a small probability of success, nevertheless using the self-reducibility of SAT, this should still give a randomized algorithm for finding satisfying assignments, and therefore NP = RP.

Comment: @Emil Jeřábek This was what I want to make sure of. Thanks!